# systemtap remote debug user process with source code

Tags: remote-debugging, systemtap

I have a stripped version (without symbol table) of `mongod` running on machine A, it is a production server.
On machine B I have the source code and a non-stripped `mongod` binary (with symbol table).
I want to remote debug a production issue with:

```
stap --remote ssh://root@A 1.stp
```

A probe like this one works:

```
probe process("/opt/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.5/bin/mongod").thread.begin {
                printf("get Thread : %d \n ", tid())
}
```

but this other probe:

```
process("/opt/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.5/bin/mongod").function("assembleResponse@src/mongo/db/instance.cpp").call
```

does not.

We have the exactly same binary version on both A and B, and the binary path is the same also.  All probes work as expected on machine B.

How can I remotely debug `mongod` in this case? Is it possible?